# Obtain only newly added rows in a Google Sheets file

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am dealing with Google Sheets REST API. I want the latest created rows in my particular sheet. Is there any API method with which I can get only newly added rows inside my sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this feature is supported yet. The only possible operations are found in [Sheet Operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/sheet) and [Row and Column Operations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/rowcolumn). You can check for empty blank cells but newly added rows, I think that's not possible.

Comment: you can find workarounds for finding empty rows, but 'newly added rows' is not possible.